# Why is my function that I made getting the TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am working with pandas DataFrames and I am adding new columns for more advanced analysis. My f function is giving me an error TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. I can't figure out why, I have my f function documented in the code if you need to know what it does.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser



# Sets the max rows that can be displayed
# when the program is executed
pd.options.display.max_rows = 200



# df is the name of the dataframe, it is 
# reading the csv file containing date loaded
# from yahoo finance(Date,Open,High,Low,Close
# volume,adj close,)the name of the ticker
# is placed before _data.csv i.e. the ticker aapl
# would have a csv file named aapl_data.csv.
df = pd.read_csv("cde_data.csv")



# the following code will allow for filtering of the datafram
# based on the year, day of week (dow), and month. It then gets
# applied to the dataframe and then can be used to sort data i.e
# print(df[(df.year == 2015) & (df.month == 5) & (df.dow == 4)])
# which will give you all the days in the month of May(df.month == 5), 
# that fall on a Thursday(df.dow == 4), in the year 2015 
# (df.year == 2015)
#
#      Month          Day                      Year
# January    = 1  Monday    = 1  The year will be dispaly in a four
# February   = 2  Tuesday   = 2  digit format i.e. 2015
# March      = 3  Wednesday = 3
# April      = 4  Thursday  = 4
# May        = 5  Friday    = 5
# June       = 6
# July       = 7
# August     = 8
# September  = 9
# October    = 10
# November   = 11
# December   = 12

def year(x):
    return(x.year)
def dow(x):
    return(x.isoweekday())
def month(x):
    return(x.month)

# f is a function that checks to see if the up_down column
# has a value that is greater than, less than, or equal to 
# zero. The value in the up_down column is derived from 
# subtracting the opening price of the stock(open column) 
# from closing price of the stock(close column). If up_down 
# has a negative value than the stocks price was Down, a positive
# value then Up, and no change is Flat
def f():
    if up_down > 0:
        x = Up
    elif up_down < 0:
        x = Down
    else:
        x = Flat
return (f)


df.reset_index()

df.Date            = df.Date.apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
df['year']         = df.Date.apply(year)
df['dow']          = df.Date.apply(dow)
df['month']        = df.Date.apply(month)
df['up_down']      = df['Close'] - df['Open']
df['up_down_flat'] = df.up_down.apply(f)


df2= (df[(df.year > 1984) & (df.month == 5) & (df.dow == 1)])
print (df2)
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dframt1est.py", line 77, in <module>
    df['up_down_flat'] = df.up_down.apply(f)
  File "C:\Users\Zac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:63043)
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This a sample csv

```
      Date       Open       High     Low   Close    Volume   Adj Close  \
0    1990-04-12  26.875000  26.875000  26.625  26.625      6100  250.576036
1    1990-04-16  26.500000  26.750000  26.375  26.750       500  251.752449
2    1990-04-17  26.750000  26.875000  26.750  26.875      2300  252.928863
3    1990-04-18  26.875000  26.875000  26.500  26.625      3500  250.576036
4    1990-04-19  26.500000  26.750000  26.500  26.750       700  251.752449
5    1990-04-20  26.750000  26.875000  26.750  26.875      2100  252.928863
6    1990-04-23  26.875000  26.875000  26.750  26.875       700  252.928863
7    1990-04-24  27.000000  27.000000  26.000  26.000      2400  244.693970
8    1990-04-25  25.250000  25.250000  24.875  25.125      9300  236.459076
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `f()` function and a full error traceback

Comment: I forgot the code sorry

Comment: There is an issue with the indentation after `def  f():`.

Comment: I fixed the indent I don't know why It copied like that but it is indented right on my actual code

Comment: @ZacAttack, could you post a few rows (5-7) of a sample CSV file and a desired DF? You are using `.apply`, which is very slow/inefficient  __multiple__ times. I think it can be written in a much more efficient way

Comment: I added a sample csv sorry it took two days I just saw your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `f` as the function in `apply`. That function is called for each row in the dataframe, and needs to take the row as its parameter.

Note also that you're returning the function itself as the result; I'm pretty sure you meant to return `x` not `f`. Also, you don't seem to have defined `Up`, `Down` and `Flat` anywhere.

Comment: Yeah I meant to have x not f I changed that, but can you give me an example if possible do you mean df.up_down.apply(row)??

Comment: No, I mean that the definition of your `f` function needs to accept a parameter.

Comment: Ok I changed that but now I get the error that says   if up_down > 0:
NameError: name 'up_down' is not defined

Comment: I think you need to do an introductory programming tutorial before diving into something as complex as pandas. This is basic stuff: `up_down` should be the name of the parameter in your function.

Comment: I just don't understand sorry I have read way to many beginning books on python they are absolutely terrible, TOO SIMPLE!!!! It is a waste of time !!!! I just reviewed the chapter on functions. thank you for your help. I don't want to take anymore of your time.